# Verificar em tempo real o que tem digitado no Edittext Android

Tags: android

tenho um EditText que irá receber os dados do usuário. Ele irá clicar e digitar um número entre 1 a 10. Queria saber se tem como eu já verificar assim que ele pula para outro Edittext, se realmente ele colocou um número entre 1 e 10. Caso ele coloque além disso, surgir uma mensagem avisando disto.

A verificação de fato eu estou fazendo assim que ele clica no botão de enviar os dados. E somente após essa tarefa que faço a verificação. Tem como fazer essa verificação antes? Como citei acima?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dê um [`setOnFocusChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) no seu `EditText`. Ex:

```
seuEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) { //perdeu o foco
               Integer numero = Integer.parseInt(seuEditText.getText().toString()); //pega o número
               if (numero <=0 && numero >10) { //verifica se está entre 1 e 10
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Número incorreto",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //mostra a msg
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo, deu certo aqui.